# Preg replace php delete after character

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a URL like this : `www.test.fr/dir/file.html#hello` I would delete everything after the character `#`. I have try this `/#[a-z0-9]+/`

Comment: I don't feel like answering and getting the points... but it's way better to use the PHP $_SERVER variables.... http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php If you read this article, you can find lots of reserved variables that can help you with URLs, I think that `REQUEST_URI`, `SERVER_NAME` and `PHP_SELF` are great to check out.

Comment: Exact, your response is good, but in my case I get my url through CURL. PHP `$_SERVER` work in this case ? @Zeke

Comment: Yes, you don't have to use cURL to get your own URL... `$_SERVER` variables are reserved and work in any PHP version... but you need to code it in a specific way to get the expected result... which I honestly don't feel like doing it right now. Anyway it will work with `preg_replace`, but I think `$_SERVER` is "cleaner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is almost correct, this works just fine:

```
$new = preg_replace('/#[a-z0-9]+/', '', 'www.test.fr/dir/file.html#hello');
print ($new);

prints:
www.test.fr/dir/file.html
```

You can test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) by '#' and get the first position. Something like this:

```
$url = "www.test.fr/dir/file.html#hello";
$result = explode("#",$url)[0];
```